# Laravel 5. Get redirected variable in View 'form' to Controller

Tags: laravel, variables

Can not get already returned variable in View into Controller.

I have this case: In View 1 there is a select in the form, the data from this catches the Controller and sends it to View 2, where it is displayed.
View 2 has its own input form. 
I'm trying to get $data and new inputs from View 2 together...

View 2:

```
form method="POST" action="{{route(catch)}}"
    h5 
       id="index1"{!!$date!!}
    /h5
    ...
/form
```

Route:

```
Route::post('/results', 'Controller_2@store')->name('catch');
```

Controller_2:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
   $var = $request->get('index1');
   return $var;
}
```

Comment: you can pass data using the name attribute not the id i think that's the problem ex: `< input name="index1" id="index1" value="{!!$date!!}">`

Comment: Yeah! That's it! Thank You very much!!!

Comment: glad to help, can you please upvote my comment? , thank you

Comment: Of course! Sorry, I am new here... How can I do that?I found this information: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) but there is no any check mark.

Comment: you can see a flag beside my comment, there is an arrow above it click it, thank you :)

Comment: Here is an answer from Support: It is not possible to mark a comment as the accepted answer. If someone solved your problem in the comments, you'll need to either ask them to move the information into a proper answer, or post an answer yourself explaining how you solved the problem.

Comment: @Eslam please write your answer at the bottom of the question (not a comment), that I could confirm, thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass data using the name attribute not the id i think that's the problem ex:

`< input name="index1" id="index1" value="{!!$date!!}">`